# `expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'fixed))` ignored

Tags: yasnippet

I have the following in a snippet's header

```
expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'fixed))
```

...but when I attempt to insert the snippet, I still get *a lot* of unwanted indentation.

What else can I do to prevent such indentation?

---

I'm using version 20161022.646 of yasnippet, and version 25.1.1 of Emacs.

Comment: Try updating yasnippet? https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/pull/838

Comment: @npostavs: Thanks; I installed yasnippets via Emacs packages, and it does not show that any updates are available.

Comment: Try `M-x package-refresh-contents` I guess? I've pushed 0.12.1 just a few weeks ago, available both on MELPA and GNU ELPA.

Comment: @npostavs: thanks; I had to delete and re-install the package, but I finally got 0.12.1 installed, and that took care of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in versions of yasnippet earlier than 0.12.1 (or somewhere around 20170723.xxx in the MELPA "version" numbering).  The best way to fix is to update yasnippet.

Possible workarounds would involve setting `yas-indent-line` to `fixed` globally instead of per-snippet.

See also [joaotavora/yasnippet#838: Avoid to indent snippets having setup `(yas-indent-line 'fixed)`](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/pull/838).